# Python ssh library that does not use threading behind-the-scenes?

Tags: python, multithreading, ssh, multiprocessing, futex

We are having issues mixing threads and forks that is basically the same as described in this blog article: http://rachelbythebay.com/w/2011/06/07/forked/

(mixing threads and forks is causing some child processes to hang on a FUTEX call)

Her analysis is basically that their SSH libraries are creating all sorts of threads, and she concludes that they need to **not use ssh**

We need ssh, does anyone know of a python ssh library that does not spawn threads?

Comment: What are you using at the moment?

Comment: Umm, I only know of [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) and [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/) (which is good for admin tasks and stuff) - can't say I'm aware of their internals though

Comment: Can't you invoke `ssh` using the `subprocess` module and running a command on the remote server through it? This way, you're not relying on any ssh libraries so you don't have to deal with threading. I don't know how complex your situation is, but that's what i would do.

Answer (score 0):

SSH is a quite complicated protocol that supports various things like port forwarding, X forwarding, tty stuff and more so it is unlikely that there are "simple" implementations.

As for multithreading, there is twisted.conch which has the downside of having to run a reactor, although it might be easier to integrate.

Another solution would be to do your SSH stuff in workers with python's `multiprocessing` package. These workers would not need to fork and would take units of work, do the necessary ssh stuff and report back the results.

Comment: The `multiprocessing` module does use `fork` on Unix, and also it does use threads, even though it depends on the task. If the OP wants to use a stdlib module than `subprocess` is the best choice I think.

Comment: `multiprocessing` uses processes, not threads. This allows to isolate the app with forking logic from the multithreaded ssh library and communicate over pipes.

Comment: The `multiprocessing` module **does** use threads to deal with processes. Just check the code for the `Queue` or the `Pool` objects for example. If you want to have control over threads and processes you must use `subprocess`.